# How to establish saddle point?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

For didactic purposes I study a critical point of a function `f[x_, y_] := 3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2` at the origin.

Its plot

```
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1/4, 1/4}, {y, -1/4, 1/4}]
```

[image]

does not clearly say whether  this is [a saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)
or a local minimum.

Of course, I may consider `f[x,y]` along a straight line `y==0`, where it has a minimum at `x==0`, and along a parabola `y==2*x^2`
where it, being equal to `-x^4`, has a maximum at `x==0`, but this is a trick, not a systematic approach.
The same drawback in

```
Resolve[ForAll[r, r > 0, Exists[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= r^2 && 3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2 > 0]], Reals]
```

together with

```
Resolve[ForAll[r, r > 0, Exists[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= r^2 && 3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2 < 0]], Reals]
```

though both say `True`.

Because of this reason  I try

```
Maximize[{3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2,  x^2 + y^2 == r^2 && r > 0 && r < 1/4}, {x, y}]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{r^2, Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, -Infinity],  {x -> Piecewise[{{Root[(1 - 16*r^2)*#1^4 + 10*#1^6 + 9*#1^8 & , 1], Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate],  y -> Piecewise[{{2*Root[(1 - 16*r^2)*#1^4 + 10*#1^6 + 9*#1^8 & , 1]^2 - Sqrt[r^2 + Root[(1 - 16*r^2)*#1^4 + 10*#1^6 + 9*#1^8 & , 1]^4],  Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate]}}`

which is well and

```
Minimize[{3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2, x^2 + y^2 == r^2 && r > 0 && r < 1/4}, {x, y}]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2], Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}},  Infinity],  {x -> Piecewise[{{Root[r^4 - 2*r^2*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2] +  Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2]^2 +  (-2*r^2 + 2*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2])*#1^2 +  (1 - 10*r^2 - 6*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2])*#1^4 + 10*#1^6 +  9*#1^8 & , 1], Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate],  y -> Piecewise[{{2*Root[r^4 - 2*r^2*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2] +  Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2]^2 +  (-2*r^2 + 2*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2])*#1^2 +  (1 - 10*r^2 - 6*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2])*#1^4 + 10*#1^6 +  9*#1^8 & , 1]^2 - Sqrt[Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2] +  Root[r^4 - 2*r^2*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2] +  Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2]^2 +  (-2*r^2 + 2*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2])*#1^2 +  (1 - 10*r^2 - 6*Root[-r^4 - 40*r^6 - 144*r^8 + (-1 - 48*r^2 - 360*r^4 - 864*r^6)*#1 + (72 - 1296*r^4)*#1^2 + 432*#1^3 & , 2])*#1^4 + 10*#1^6 +  9*#1^8 & , 1]^4], Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate]}}`

which is not well.

```
Plot[Minimize[{3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2, x^2 + y^2 == r^2 && r > 0 && r < 1/4}, {x, y}][[1]], {r, 0, 1/4}]
```

[image]

shows negative values, but doesn't prove it.
The commands

```
Root[-r^4 - 40 r^6 -  144 r^8 + (-1 - 48 r^2 - 360 r^4 - 864 r^6) #1 + (72 - 1296 r^4) #1^2 + 432 #1^3 &, 2] /. r -> 0
```

> `0`

together with

```
Maximize[{D[Root[-r^4 - 40 r^6 - 144 r^8 + (-1 - 48 r^2 - 360 r^4 - 864 r^6) #1 + (72 -1296 r^4) #1^2 + 432 #1^3 &, 2], r], r >= 0 && r <= 1/4}, r]
```

> `{0, {r -> 0}}`

complete the proof.

The question is: is there a simpler way to establish the origin as the saddle point?

Comment: BTW, the `Student` package of Maple which is an advantage of Maple over Mathematica produces an incorrect result `LocalMin = [], LocalMax = [], Saddle = []` by `Student:-MultivariateCalculus:-SecondDerivativeTest(3*x^4 - 4*x^2*y + y^2, [x, y] = [0, 0])`.

Comment: The Hessian at the critical point gives the answer. Look it up

Comment: @DanielHuber: Unfortuately, no answer in this case  since the Hessian at the origin is `{{0, 0} {0, 2}}`. This is a hard matter: see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Singularities_of_differentiable_mappings) for more info.

Comment: Well, then you must get the next higher derivatives. It is nothing else than a series expansion. The lowest non-zero term will determine the behavior.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Think of `Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(x^2+y^2)],x^2+y^2!=0},{0,True}}]`. It seems you didn't look in  the linked article of Encyclopedia of Mathematica. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary answer to the question.

```
Minimize[{3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2, x == r && r> 0 && r < 1/4 && y >= -r && y <= r},{x,y}]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{-r^4, Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Infinity], {x -> Piecewise[{{r, Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate],  y -> Piecewise[{{2*r^2, Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate]}}`

```
Maximize[{3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2,x == r && r > 0 && r < 1/4 && y >= -r && y <= r}, {x,y}]
```

> `{Piecewise[{{r^2 + 4*r^3 + 3*r^4, Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, -Infinity], {x -> Piecewise[{{r, Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate],  y -> Piecewise[{{2*r^2 - Sqrt[r^2*(1 + 2*r)^2], Inequality[0, Less, r, Less, 1/4]}}, Indeterminate]}}`

Therefore, any neighbourhood of the origin includes the points, where `f[x,y]>0`, and the points, where `f[x,y]<0`.This answer the question.

Comment: Is it really a saddle point? The contour lines do not cross! `Plot3D[3 x^4 - 4 x^2 y + y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -5, 10}, Mesh -> 20,  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`

Comment: @rmw: Indeed, the same with `Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -5, 10}, Mesh -> 20,    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]`. Think of a publication of your result in a journal.